# How would I add a margin-top to just the image part of the span?

Tags: html, css

So I got a span with a sparkling effect with an image before the text but for some reason the image is aligned to the top. When I get rid of the image part in my span and just use a .. before it, it works fine.

Currently:
[image: currently]

Desired result:
[image: desired_result]

css:

```css
.sapphire-member { 
    color: #0033ff;
    background-image: url(http://resources.guild-hosting.net/201604011348/themes/core/images/tag_fx/sparkle_yellow.gif);
}
.sapphire-member:before {
    content: url(https://puu.sh/D9zBw/ca0f811bca.png);
}
```

html:

```html
<span class='sapphire-member'>Test</span>
```

current html code for desired result with img tag:

```html
<img src="https://puu.sh/D9zBw/ca0f811bca.png" /><span class='sapphire-member'>
```

So basically I want to know if it's possible to get the desired result without using the img tag?

Comment: did you play with vertical-align? .. it should achieve what you want

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfLajuqr/

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` is probably what you're after. You want to avoid hard-coding amounts like `margin-top` for vertical centering because what if the font size or some other positioning changes? I would suggest:

```
<span class='sapphire-member'>Test</span>
```

```
.sapphire-member { 
    color: #0033ff;
    background-image: url(http://resources.guild-hosting.net/201604011348/themes/core/images/tag_fx/sparkle_yellow.gif);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.sapphire-member:before {
    content: url(https://puu.sh/D9zBw/ca0f811bca.png);
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

[image: test image]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMwGXN